# How to disable Metal in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, metal

Unity has a setting to pick the Graphics API automatically.

For some reason my game has a much lower performance when using Metal; for now I'd like to not have Metal as an option but still be able to make it pick Open GL ES 2.0 or 3.0 automatically.

I'm using Unity 5.0.

Comment: This question is primarily asking how to accomplish a task within the configuration of a popular game development tool, Unity.  Since it's about a tool with a specialized area of interest, not programming per se, it belongs on the Game Dev Stack Exchange.  I believe it's too old to migrate, however.

Comment: unity is used for far more than games. there are productivity appsmafe with unity. Unity is just another IDE albeit one with many features. as such this question is totally on topic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Unity **5.0**, lee's answer may be the answer.
From Unity **5.1**, you can specify preferable APIs and their priority in Player settings.

> https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.1 :
>   Graphics: Added a way to specify graphics APIs explicitly in player settings (defaults to "automatic" for each platform). For example, you could specify you only want to support Metal+ES2 in iOS builds, or only DX11 (without DX9 fallback) on Windows builds etc. This replaces the "Use DX11" and "Target iOS/GLES Graphics" settings.

In the following example, ES3 will be picked prior to ES2 if available, and Metal will not be picked even if available.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be......

In the "Preprocessor.h"

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_8_0) && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    #define UNITY_CAN_USE_METAL     0
#else
    #define UNITY_CAN_USE_METAL     0
#endif
```